# Can't put image on top on Telegraph article

Tags: api, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I would like to put a photo on the top in a telegraph article.
Like in this image

[image]

I'm using a telegraph api found on github,  but it doesn't matter which one this is: I could write my own library to do this, but with both method I can't get to put an image on the topmost of the article **and then the actual title and article**

Here what I'm able to do.

[image]

I tried to put the html code for the image **first** in my code, but I get nonetheless the Article title first.

What am I missing?
Working with Python 3 and Linux

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If u are using PC it's really easy. just drag the img and drop it in header/title section. then write ur title.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP

```
$test = 
    array(
        array("tag" => "figure", "children" => 
            array(
                array("tag" => "img", "attrs" => array("src" => "https://image.jpg")),
            )
        ), 
        array("tag" => "p", "children" => array("test"))
    );

    print_r(json_encode($test));
    //[{"tag":"figure","children":[{"tag":"img","attrs":{"src":"https:\/\/image.jpg"}}]},{"tag":"p","children":["test"]}]
```

Work for me

Answer (score -1):

Right now telegram only supports these HTML tags:

```
<a> <strong> <em> <b> <i> <pre> <code>
```

It means you cannot have such an article but you can have an image and add your text as a caption or using HTML's link tag you can add the image to the end of your post and use the telegram's WebPagePreview to show it at the end of the post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot understand your point. I want to **place** the image on top of the article. like in the first pic (that one with android) on **top** of the article. IT IS POSSIBLE, (look at the first pic again) but I cannot get it to place.